# measure theory -Lebesgue measure problem 1

Tags: measure-theory

Please help me to do the following problem...

For $k>0$ and $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$,let $kA=\{kx:x∈A\}$

Show that $m^{*}(kA)=k m^{*}(A)$
$A$ is measurable if and only if $kA$ is measurable.

Comment: Have you seen the definition of a measurable function yet?

Comment: It is true for intervals. Use the definition of outer measure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=x/k$. f is measurale therefore $kA=f^{-1}(A)$ is also measurable.

Now repeat the same argument using the inverse of $k$